# MySQL – Should I use last_insert_id()? or something else?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `users` that has an auto-incrementing `id` column. For every new user, I essentially need to insert three rows into three different tables, which are 1. `user`, 2. `user_content`, and 3. `user_preferences`. The rows inserted into `user_content` and `user_preferences` are referenced  by their `id`'s which correspond to each user's id (held in `user`)

How do I accomplish this?

Should I do the `INSERT INTO user` query first, obtaining that auto-incremented `id` with `last_insert_id()`, and then the other two `INSERT INTO` queries using the obtained user id? Or, is there a more concise way to do this?

(note: I am using MySQL and PHP, and if it makes a difference, I am using a `bigint` to store the `id` values in all three tables.)

Thank you!

Comment: *First*, get it working, *then* make it fast. The most optimised code won't be worth the characters used to write it if it doesn't do the right thing.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but I do try to "measure twice, cut once" when doing things such as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach that you've described (insert into `user` first, take the result of `last_insert_id()`, and use that to insert to the other two tables) is perfectly reasonable; I see nothing wrong with it.

It might be technically possible to combine the three queries and use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` MySQL function to insert values to the other two tables, but this would be significantly more complex without any corresponding benefits. Not really worth doing, in other words.

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 options:

1. PHP side using some `*_last_insert_id` (as you describe)
2. Create a trigger
3. Use a stored procedure.